# How to scale the graphics for Mac OS

Tags: display, displayport, resolution

I recently purchased [this 2k monitor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LHYIATA) on Amazon. I'm connecting my 2015 Macbook Pro 15 inch w/ retina display using a DisplayPort Mini to DisplayPort cable. I'm currently running Mac OS Mojave. These are the resolutions I can use apaprently:

[image]

1440p looks really nice, but everything is so tiny. I can zoom in on some apps, but not all of them; system fonts can't be changed at all.

1080p is a more comfortable scale but then things start to look blurry.

Is there no way to reach a happy medium? Do I just need to pick whether to sacrifice readability or aesthetic? I feel like Windows and linux have a way of setting the scale of things independent of the resolution, does such a thing exist for Mac?

**UPDATE:** I tried out TinkerTool and it only scales some things, not all of them. For example, the menu bar at the top of the screen remains the same size. Also graphical things like the traffic light buttons are unaffected. So overall it didn't really help

**UPDATE 2:** When I use my laptop by itself I see something like this:

[image]

All the options look great on the Mac screen, but the options for the monitor aren't as nice looking...

Answer (score 1):

I would download SwitchResX and try the various settings to see if you can find one you like:

https://www.madrau.com/srx_download/download.html

The optimal use for that kind of monitor is the native 2560x1440, however you write that it's too tiny for you. It would probably have been better to get a larger monitor at the same resolution (i.e. a 27" or similar for example).

With the current monitor I would try setting it a resolution that is an integer fraction of the native resolution. I.e. for example try setting it to 1280x720. You can also try 1280x720 HiDPI mode, which should look alright.

Comment: Yeah maybe a larger monitor would have been better... but I already went through the hassle of returning a 1080p one and getting this one, doing it all over again sounds like even more work on top of that

Answer (score 0):

If you hold down Option when you click on the 'Scaled' radio button, you should see a greater list of resolution options.

This will include 1280 x 720 (HiDPI), which is a 'Retina' scaling of your monitor's pixels: (i.e. just as much detail as 1440p, but everything twice the size.)

Bear in mind that other resolution sizes apart from 1440p or 720 HiDPI will require more effort, as the Mac will have to calculate fractional pixels and use more anti-aliasing.